# Reuse XlsxWriter worksheet header image

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

XlsxWriter allows to set the header for each Worksheet with `set_header`. If a workbook has a large number of worksheets, the header must be set for each worksheet. If the same image is used in all worksheets header's, the image is saved multiple times in the .xlsx file, which blows up the file size.

Is there a way to re-use the image in each worksheet header? I switched from xlsx.js to XlsxWriter, and the file size of my Excel files has increased from 300 KB to 4 MB.

Comment: Reusing duplicate images isn't currently supported by XlsxWriter.